# How to select an item from dynamically added spinner?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I am adding a spinner dynamically in a layout, as;

```
   public class FRQuestionsDetail extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextView tvCategoryType;
    private TextView tvCategoryObtainScore;
    private TextView tvCategoryTotalScore;
    private TextView tvQuestionNumber;
    private TextView tvQuestionPercent;
    private TextView tvQuestion;

    private Button btnNextQuestion;
    private Button btnPrevQuestion;
    private LinearLayout linearDynamicQuesOptions;

    private int scoringType;
    private int reviewId;
    private int reviewLocationId;
    private int reviewCategoryId;
    private int questionId;
    private int count = 0;
    private int position;
    private long categoryScore;
    private long questionScore;;
    private String reviewCategoryType;
    private String question;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> qOptionsAdapter;

    private static ArrayList<FRReviewQuestions> questionsList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question_detail_page);

        tvCategoryType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_category_type_q_detail);
        tvCategoryObtainScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_category_score_obtain_q_detail);
        tvCategoryTotalScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_category_score_total_q_detail);
        tvQuestionNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_question_number);
        tvQuestionPercent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_question_percent);
        tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_question);

        btnNextQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_nextQuestion);
        btnPrevQuestion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_prevQuestion);
        linearDynamicQuesOptions = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_dynamic_options);

        btnNextQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPrevQuestion.setOnClickListener(this);

        SharedPreferences savedReviewPref = getSharedPreferences(
                Configuration.START_REVIEW, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        scoringType = savedReviewPref.getInt(
                Configuration.REVIEW_TEMPLATE_SCORING_TYPE, 0);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        reviewLocationId = extras.getInt("reviewLocationId");
        reviewId = extras.getInt("reviewId");
        reviewCategoryId = extras.getInt("reviewCategoryId");
        reviewCategoryType = extras.getString("reviewCategoryType");
        questionId = extras.getInt("questionId");
        categoryScore = extras.getLong("categoryScore");
        questionScore = extras.getLong("questionScore");
        position = extras.getInt("position");
        question = extras.getString("question");
        position = position + 1;
        questionsList = getQuestionDbContent();
        count = FRReviewQuestionsTable.countQuestions;

        tvCategoryType.setText(reviewCategoryType);

        if (scoringType == 3) {
            tvCategoryTotalScore.setText("(" + categoryScore + "%)");
            // tvQuestionPercent.setText(" (" + questionScore + "%)" );
        } else if (scoringType == 2) {
            tvCategoryTotalScore.setText("(" + categoryScore + ")");
            // tvQuestionPercent.setText(" (" + questionScore + ")" );
        } else if (scoringType == 1) {
            tvCategoryTotalScore.setText(" ");
            // tvQuestionPercent.setText(" ");
        }

        drawQuestion(position);
        // tvQuestionNumber.setText(" " + position + " of " + count);
        // tvQuestion.setText(question);
    }

    private ArrayList<FRReviewQuestions> getQuestionDbContent() {
        ArrayList<FRReviewQuestions> arrayQuestions = new ArrayList<FRReviewQuestions>();

        FRReviewQuestionsTable db = new FRReviewQuestionsTable(
                FRQuestionsDetail.this);
        arrayQuestions = db
                .getReviewQuestionWrtIdFromDB(
                        "review_question_id,review_question_category_id,review_question,review_question_type,review_question_is_pic_req,review_question_score,review_question_is_deleted,review_question_is_ans_req,review_question_max_length,review_question_last_sync_date",
                        reviewCategoryId);
        db.CloseDB();

        return arrayQuestions;
    }

    public void drawQuestion(int index) {
        FRReviewQuestions questions = new FRReviewQuestions();
        questions = questionsList.get(index - 1);
        String ques = questions.getReviewQuestion();
        int quesId = questions.getReviewQuestionId();
        int isAnsReq = questions.getIsAnsReq();
        int questionType = questions.getQuestionType();
        long maxLength = questions.getMaxLength();
        long questionScore = questions.getQuestionScore();

        if (scoringType == 3) {
            tvQuestionPercent.setText(" (" + questionScore + "%)");
        } else if (scoringType == 2) {
            tvQuestionPercent.setText(" (" + questionScore + ")");
        } else if (scoringType == 1) {
            tvQuestionPercent.setText(" ");
        }

        tvQuestionNumber.setText(" " + index + " of " + count);
        tvQuestion.setText(ques);

        if (questionType == 1) {
            dropDownQuestion(quesId);
        } else if (questionType == 2) {

        } else if (questionType == 3) {

        } else if (questionType == 4) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    private void dropDownQuestion(int quesId) {
        ArrayList<FRQuestionOptions> arrayQuestionOptions = new ArrayList<FRQuestionOptions>();
        arrayQuestionOptions = getQuestionOptionsDbContent(quesId);

        Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
        spin.setClickable(true);
        // spin.setContentDescription("Select");
        spin.setPrompt("Select");
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

//      linearDynamicQuesOptions.addView(spin, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
//               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//               LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        qOptionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        qOptionsAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(qOptionsAdapter);

        int len = arrayQuestionOptions.size();
        FRQuestionOptions qOptions;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            qOptions = arrayQuestionOptions.get(i);
            String value = qOptions.getValue();
            qOptionsAdapter.add(value);
            qOptionsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

         linearDynamicQuesOptions.addView(spin, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btnNextQuestion) {

        } else if (v == btnPrevQuestion) {

        }
    }

    private ArrayList<FRQuestionOptions> getQuestionOptionsDbContent(
            int questionId) {
        ArrayList<FRQuestionOptions> arrayQuestionOptions = new ArrayList<FRQuestionOptions>();

        FRQuesOptionsTable db = new FRQuesOptionsTable(FRQuestionsDetail.this);
        arrayQuestionOptions = db
                .getReviewQuestionWrtIdFromDB(
                        "option_id,question_id,question_score,question_value,question_is_deleted,question_last_sync_date",
                        questionId);
        db.CloseDB();

        return arrayQuestionOptions;
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }
}
```

But when I click on the spinner, my app crashes and I got the following error.

```
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@40b5bdb0 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:562)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:179)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:433)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:265)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:260)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9320)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
03-01 11:40:31.864: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(31327):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do not know, how to select an item in the spinner or how to make a spinner selectable or clickable.

Note: My this activity is one of the activities in my ActivityGroup.
Please help me out in this. Thank You!

Comment: same thing happens, if I put that at the end.

Comment: which line indicated error in logcat?

Comment: none as it is not adding the window in the view.

Comment: @Hiral, thanks for the advice, I did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logcat says `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException` which means you are passing invalid Context somewhere.

I doubt this line

```
 Spinner spin = new Spinner(this);
```

Try using `Spinner spin=new Spinner(YourActivity.this)` or  `Spinner spin=new Spinner(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: You are right about this. It solved my problem, as instead of giving this, I should have given the context of my ActivityGroup. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

using a spinner is easy and simple. I will tell u step by step
1. Take that spinner on your layout or add it dynamically. 
like below `Spinner brand=new Spinner;` and fix it on any layout
but if u add this statically on your layout then do this
 `brand=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.brand);`

2.Add items in the array to show

```
array_spinner=new String[4];
   array_spinner[0]="BFT";
   array_spinner[1]="GFP";
   array_spinner[2]="FSS";
   array_spinner[3]="others";
```

3.select any item from the spinner

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
          brand.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is all about the spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing very complex code this might help

Add your data to arraylist and use it like below

```
ArrayList<Client > proarray;
Spinner spn = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spn);
spn.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr));
```

and to get the id or any field from your record use

```
int id = proarray.get(spn.getSelectedItemPosition()).id;
```

or implement

```
onitemSelectedListener()
```

and pass the selected position to above.